# CloudFoundry nodeJS tutorial is out of date?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm following the [nodeJS tutorial](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/nodejs/nodejs.html) and as I get the point of pushing the application to Cloudfoundry.com the push flow in the tutorial and the one I see are very different.
I use vmc 0.999 and this is what I see:

> Name> hello-node
>
> Instances> 1
>
> 1: node 2: other Framework> node
>
> 1: node 2: node06 3: node08 4: other Runtime> 3
>
> 1: 64M 2: 128M 3: 256M 4: 512M 5: 1G 6: 2G Memory Limit> 64M
>
> Creating ido-hello-node... OK
>
> 1: ido-hello-node.cloudfoundry.com 2: none URL>
>   ido-hello-node.cloudfoundry.com
>
> Updating ido-hello-node... OK
>
> Create services for application?> n
>
> Save configuration?> y
>
> Saving to manifest.yml... OK Uploading ido-hello-node... OK Using
>   manifest file manifest.yml
>
> Starting ido-hello-node... OK Checking ido-hello-node

Am I doing something wrong or is the tutorial simply out-dated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vmc 0.999 so I am not sure what version you actually have - the latest version as of now (obtained by typing 'gem install vmc --pre') is vmc-0.5.0-rc1. You can check which version you have using 'vmc --version'

Yes, the tutorials at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com are outdated and we are busy working on updated versions at http://cloudfoundry.github.com.

You can find the latest Node tutorial here: http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/javascript/

If you find any mistakes or would like to suggest additions please feel free to contribute by sending a Github pull request.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about the version. It is vmc 0.4.7. You are right

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application pushed successfully. Was there a problem running it?

The vmc command is changing, and the docs you reference may be getting out of date. New docs are being created and published here: http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/javascript/. These docs are a work-in-progress, but are more up to date.